# React router url params not stored in props

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a simple routes:

```
import Foo from './Foo';
import Bar from './Bar';

const Routes = (
    <ReactRouter.Route handler={App} path="/">
        <ReactRouter.Route path="foo" handler={Foo} />
        <ReactRouter.Route path="foo/:bar" handler={Bar} />
    </ReactRouter.Route>
);
```

and components:

```
const Foo = React.createClass({
...
})

...

const Bar = React.createClass({
    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('props', this.props.params);
    },
    render() {
        console.log(this.props.params);
        return (
            <div>Bar Component</div>
        );
    }
});

export default Bar;
```

When I navigate to `/foo` I get my `Foo` component rendered. When I navigate to `/foo/something` I get my `Bar` component rendered but I my `props` object is empty. I was assuming I should have `this.props.params` with `bar = something` there.
I was following http://rackt.github.io/react-router/#Router Overview and also [Nested details route with react-router not rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26474617/nested-details-route-with-react-router-not-rendering) but with no luck.

Comment: Regarding to react router docs when you specify Route with /foo/:something then you should have props.params.something.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31062102/react-component-this-props-is-always-empty

Comment: Sorry I'm using 0.13.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it.

```
const Bar = React.createClass({
    contextTypes: {
        'router': React.PropTypes.func
    },
    render() {
        const router = this.context.router;
        const bar = router.getCurrentParams().bar;
        return (
            <div>{bar}</div>
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: tih solution is not working with RR 0.12.4 but only RR 0.13.x. This is why I don't tell you this solution.

Answer (score 1):

The advice for react router 13.3 is to use mixins and to not use context.
They also say to skip 13.2. See https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/UPGRADE_GUIDE.md

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using RR 0.12.4 try this:

```
const Bar = React.createClass({
    mixins: [ ReactRouter.State ],
    render() {
        console.log(this.getParams().bar);
        return (
            <div>Bar Component</div>
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm trying to avoid mixins due to being depracated in 0.13.

Comment: @DeBoer Why you don't use RR 0.13.3 ?

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I was using 0.13.2